# Setup mailgun with parse-server on Heroku

Tags: parse-server, mailgun

I am trying to set up mailgun for use with parse-server app on Heroku.

The recommended API is

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter

But instructions on how to actually achieve this are non existent.

--------- EDIT -----------

Followed instructions and server pushes to Heroku.  Though i am still not receiving emails.  Im just using mailgun sandbox and have authorised and activated a recipient.

Im not sure about specifying the path to templates or:

```
fromAddress: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
```

This wasn't supplied by mailgun so i have just entered no-reply@myservername.heroku

This obviously isnt valid?

index.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var path = require('path');

const resolve = require('path').resolve;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
    console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}


var api = new ParseServer({
    //**** General Settings ****//

    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
    maxUploadSize: '500mb',

    //**** Security Settings ****//
    // allowClientClassCreation: process.env.CLIENT_CLASS_CREATION || false, 
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret! 

    //**** Live Query ****//
    // liveQuery: {
    //  classNames: ["TestObject", "Place", "Team", "Player", "ChatMessage"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
    // },


      //**** File Storage ****//
      filesAdapter: new S3Adapter({
          accessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY || '',
          secretKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY || '',
          bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || '',
          directAccess: true
     }),

    //**** Email Verification ****//
    /* Enable email verification */
    // verifyUserEmails: true,
    /* The public URL of your app */
    // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.


    publicServerURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || '',
    appName: process.env.APP_NAME || '',

     emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-mailgun',
        options: {
            fromAddress: process.env.EMAIL_FROM || '',
            domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN || '',
            apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY  || '',

            templates: {
              passwordResetEmail: {
              subject: 'Reset your password',
              pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, 'https:/myparseserveronheroku.herokuapp.com/node_modules/parse-server-mailgun-adapter/test/email-templates/password_reset_email.txt'),
              pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, 'https:/myparseserveronheroku.herokuapp.com/node_modules/parse-server-mailgun-adapter/test/email-templates/password_reset_email.html'),
              callback: (user) => { return { firstName: user.get('firstName') }}
              // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
              },
              verificationEmail: {
              subject: 'Confirm your account',
              pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, 'https:/myparseserveronheroku.herokuapp.com/node_modules/parse-server-mailgun-adapter/test/email-templates/verification_email.txt'),
              pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, 'https:/myparseserveronheroku.herokuapp.com/node_modules/parse-server-mailgun-adapter/test/email-templates/verification_email.html'),
              callback: (user) => { return { firstName: user.get('firstName') }}
              // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates 
              }
            }
        }
     }

});
```

My swift code to send password reset says that the message has been sent, so i assume that everything Cliff has told me is correct and the server side is set up ok, probably just something stupid that i have done with the variables.

```
    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: emailAddress!) { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // display error message
            let userMessage: String = error!.localizedDescription
            GeneralFunctions.createAlert(errorTitle: "Oops...", errorMessage: userMessage, className: self )
        } else {
            // display success message
            let userMessage: String = "An new password was sent to \(emailAddress!)"
            GeneralFunctions.createAlert(errorTitle: "Hooray...", errorMessage: userMessage, className: self )
        }
    }
```

----------- EDIT ----------

Verbose log after trying reset password

```
email=my-verified-email@email.com.au
2017-02-06T00:44:25.788619+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/requestPasswordReset: {
2017-02-06T00:44:25.788623+00:00 app[web.1]:   "response": {}
2017-02-06T00:44:25.788625+00:00 app[web.1]: } 
2017-02-06T00:44:25.797455+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/https:/myparseserveronheroku.herokuapp.com/node_modules/parse-server-mailgun-adapter/test/email-templates/password_reset_email.txt'
2017-02-06T00:44:25.797458+00:00 app[web.1]:   errno: -2,
2017-02-06T00:44:25.797459+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ENOENT',
2017-02-06T00:44:25.797459+00:00 app[web.1]:   syscall: 'open',
2017-02-06T00:44:25.797462+00:00 app[web.1]:   path: '/app/https:/myparseserveronheroku.herokuapp.com/node_modules/parse-server-mailgun-adapter/test/email-templates/password_reset_email.txt' }
2017-02-06T00:44:25.792191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/requestPasswordReset" host=myparseserveronheroku.herokuapp.com request_id=666ff3e0-db4a-4e76-b7b5-6353edc7e15a fwd="111.111.111.11" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=81ms status=200 bytes=483
```

So definitely looks like its trying to send from a template that doesn't exist.  Im not sure how to specify path here,  i had thought that all these directories including node_modules/parse-server-mailgun-adapter/test/email-templates were pushed to Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
npm install --save parse-server-mailgun
```

Then in your index.js file you can set it up as follows in the initialize:

```
 publicServerURL: 'http://MY_HEROKU_APP.herokuapp.com/parse', 
 appName: 'MY_APP',
 emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-mailgun',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'no-reply@example.com',
      domain: 'example.com',
      apiKey: 'key-XXXXXX',
    }
 }
```

The default Mailgun adapter that comes with the Parse Server, you need to set a `fromAddres`, and the domain and `apiKey` provided by Mailgun. In addition, you also need to configure the templates you want to use. You must provide at least a plain-text version for each template. The html versions are optional.

```
verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-mailgun',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from 
      fromAddress: 'YourApp <noreply@yourapp.com>',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com 
      domain: 'example.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com 
      apiKey: 'key-mykey',
      // The template section 
      templates: {
        passwordResetEmail: {
          subject: 'Reset your password',
          pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/templates/password_reset_email.txt'),
          pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/templates/password_reset_email.html'),
          callback: (user) => { return { firstName: user.get('firstName') }}
          // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates 
        },
        verificationEmail: {
          subject: 'Confirm your account',
          pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/templates/verification_email.txt'),
          pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/templates/verification_email.html'),
          callback: (user) => { return { firstName: user.get('firstName') }}
          // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates 
        },
        customEmailAlert: {
          subject: 'Urgent notification!',
          pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/templates/custom_alert.txt'),
          pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/templates/custom_alert.html'),
        }
      }
    }
```

Reference to the NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-mailgun

Comment: Thanks.  I'll let you know how I get in with this!

Comment: Say were just going to use the templates provided, how do you specify the path to these? /parse-server/node_modules/parse-server-mailgun/test

Comment: Your setup is correct so thats good. Path is incorrect. __dirname is The directory name of the current module. So look and see what path your index.js is in then you build your path from there. No https or domain names. True paths

Comment: I had tried it without the https but I'm a muppet and had a forward slash at the start of the path. /node_modules/.  Thanks heaps for the help.

Comment: So the email comes through, however i get an error when i click the reset link                                                                                                         Cannot GET /apps/myappid/request_password_reset?token=CqqIJi3PzyHEMouZpVjP421pm&username=test@test.com

Comment: You are correct.  For some reason when i set up on Heroku the SERVER_URL environment var did not work with /parse.  If i just create a new var with /parse problem solved.  I should really go back through and make sure this is the case, I'm pretty sure i was changing things all over trying to get it running.

Comment: publicServerURL is just for things like that. So you will be fine! Enjoy and best of luck with your build