# Parse-Server-Mailgun : How to edit templates and have them pushed to server

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server, mailgun

This is an extension to my previous question:

[Setup mailgun with parse-server on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050364/setup-mailgun-with-parse-server-on-heroku)

When you run '$ npm install parse-server-mailgun' it installs a bunch of directories and files on my current directory.  However when i edit any of these, specifically the email templates, or anything thing that isnt in the main root directory of my parse-server-example folder, they don't push to Heroku.

I assume, if this is the case that it must just be pushing the main config files located in the root dir and then pulling the rest from nom somewhere?

How to i push the entire directory and all its sub folder/files to my Heroku server?  Or edit the email templates already on the server?

Sorry this is a bit f a stupid question probably.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the templates from the package's folder. Instead, create your own templates in your project's directory, and then reference those when initializing ParseServer. Then simply add these new files to your git repository and they'll be available on the server.

For instance:

> ```
> emailAdapter: {
>     module: 'parse-server-mailgun',
>     options: {
>         // The address that your emails come from
>         fromAddress: 'Hello <hello@example.com>',
>         // Your domain from mailgun.com
>         domain: config.Mailgun.domain,
>         // Your API key from mailgun.com
>         apiKey: config.Mailgun.api,
>         templates: {
>             verificationEmail: {
>                 subject: 'Please verify your e-mail for Example.com',
>                 pathPlainText: './email/emailVerification/index.txt',
>                 pathHtml: './email/emailVerification/index.html',
>                 callback: function (user) { return { firstName: user.get('firstName') }; }
>                 // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix. Put them in the root directory of the build.  They will automatically be committed tot he server

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [mail adapter](https://github.com/macarthuror/parse-smtp-template) is really easy to use and also you can use it to multi language mails.

Hope that can help you.

A little example of how you can use it.

```js
emailAdapter: {
  module: 'parse-smtp-template',
  options: {
    ...
    template: true,
    templatePath: "views/templates/template.html",

    // Custome options to your emails
    // You can add more options if you need
    passwordOptions: {
        subject: "Password recovery",
        body: "Custome pasword recovery email body",
        btn: "Recover your password"
        /* --EXTRA PARAMETERS--
        others: {
          extraParameter
        }
        */
    },
    confirmOptions: {
        subject: "E-mail confirmation",
        body: "Custome email confirmation body",
        btn: "confirm your email"
    },
  }
}
```

https://github.com/macarthuror/parse-smtp-template